# Reconstructing curve from gradient

Tags: python, numpy, math, numerical-methods

Suppose I have a curve, and then I estimate its gradient via finite differences by using `np.gradient`. Given an initial point x[0] and the gradient vector, how can I reconstruct the original curve? Mathematically I see its possible given this system of equations, but I'm not certain how to do it programmatically.

Here is a simple example of my problem, where I have sin(x) and I compute the numerical difference, which matches cos(x).

```
test = np.vectorize(np.sin)(x)
numerical_grad = np.gradient(test, 30./100)
analytical_grad = np.vectorize(np.cos)(x)

## Plot data.
ax.plot(test, label='data', marker='o')
ax.plot(numerical_grad, label='gradient')
ax.plot(analytical_grad, label='proof', alpha=0.5)
ax.legend();
```

[image: Sine and its gradient.]

Comment: Look into cubic splines (and other smooth curve interpolation methods) unless you want your curve to have a specific functional form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it, by using numpy's `trapz` function (trapezoidal rule integration).

Following up on the code I presented on the question, to reproduce the input array `test`, we do:

```
x = np.linspace(1, 30, 100)
integral = list()
for t in range(len(x)):
    integral.append(test[0] + np.trapz(numerical_grad[:t+1], x[:t+1]))
```

The integral array then contains the results of the numerical integration.

Comment: This is pretty inefficient because `trapz` will redo accumulations from scratch at every invocation, whereas incremental computation is possible.

Comment: And for such a smooth function, Simpson's rule should give better accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore initial curve using integration.

As life example: If you have function for position for 1D moving, you can get function for velocity as derivative (gradient)

```
 v(t) = s(t)' = ds / dt
```

And having velocity, you can potentially get position (not all functions are integrable analytically - in this case numerical integration is used) with some unknown constant (shift) added - and with initial position you can restore exact value

```
s(T) = Integral[from 0 to T](v(t)dt) + s(0)
```